# Importing components dynamically in angular with a dynamic value in argument of import()

Tags: angular, import, angular-components

```
componentToBeLoaded ;
import('src/app/common/exact-path-to-the-component/required.component').then((value) => {
this.componentTobeLoaded = value['RequiredComponent']
          })
```

It runs fine.

```
componentToBeLoaded ;
const path = 'src/app/common/exact-path-to-the-component/required.component'
import(path).then((value) => {
this.componentTobeLoaded = value['RequiredComponent']
          })
```

Gives Error :  **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'src/app/common/exact-path-to-the-component/required.component'.**

When I provide exact path to the component, import runs fine. But if i try to provide the path dynamically (using variable , as named path above), it gives error.

Comment: This is not possible because the import happens at build time whereas your logic runs at runtime. If anything you need to import all possible components and implement a mapping logic that returns the respective component.

Comment: Can you explain with some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
const componentRelativePath: string = componentAbsolutePath.replace('src/app/', '').replace('.component', '');
        
    import(`src/app/${componentRelativePath}.component`).then((value) => {
                  this.componentTobeLoaded = value[RequiredComponent];
                });
```

This one worked fine for me.